# Why I should use mergemap instead of nested http call?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have created nested http call with help of RXJS library:

```
this.http.get('/api/people/1').subscribe(character => {
  this.http.get(character.homeworld).subscribe(homeworld => {
    character.homeworld = homeworld;
    this.loadedCharacter = character;
  });
```

But I was told by some of my teem mets that correct way to fetch data from API using streams and RXJS is:

```
this.homeworld = this.http
  .get('/api/people/1')
  .pipe(mergeMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld)));
```

Please tell me why the second approach is better than the first. Why I should use
mergemap and why it's better then use nested http call? ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about nested http calls, it's about nested subscription which it's RxJS antipattern.
RxJS is the library which solves problems reactively and declaratively. It means that your data flow in application should be described as streams. Good patterns in RxJS assume that entire flow should be written as one lazy loaded streams. In your case the entire flow is: `fetch person with id=1 -> determine homeworld -> fetch homeworld`. So you don't mind actually about person details, but about `homeworld`.
Please notice, that in second case you don't call any http method, you only compose lazy stream. It allows to you use this stream in place or subscribe it in another place without storing state. This is huge advantage, that you don't care about state or intermediate state (imperative approach).

What's more, when you use `.subscribe()` you create subscription that should be managed in service/component lifecycle. If you create one stream flow, only one subscription is created, so subscription managing is just easier.
I know, that http.get/post observable is completed after data is fetched, but what if you leave component where that http call was made? Code will execute side-effects in scope which doesn't exist.

I think very good explanation you will find also in https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/when-to-subscribe-a83332ae053